# Filtering a list of dictionaries using its values in python

Tags: python, json

I have a list of dictionaries that I would like to filter and create a vector that corresponds to the list values. That list files contains several entries, where each one has a field `time, item, state: {values1, value2, value3}`. The variable `item` could take the following 11 values `[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ... 1.0]`. For each of whose values I would like to find the correspondent `value3` values and create a vector of 11 elements where each one should correspond to `value3` for the associated `item` variable. For example if my list is:

```
my_json = [{'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 4, 13, 42, 55, 613000), 'item': 0.3, 'state': {'value1': 0.0, 'value2': 0.167, 'value3': 0.833}}
{'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 6, 9, 40, 54, 44000), 'item': 0.6, 'state': {'value1': 0.0, 'value2': 0.273, 'value3': 0.727}}
{'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 6, 10, 0, 16, 507000), 'item': 0.5, 'state': {'value1': 0.0, 'value2': 0.0, 'value3': 1.0}}
{'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 6, 10, 37, 16, 769000), 'item': 0.5, 'state': {'value1': 0.0, 'value2': 0.0, 'value3': 1.0}}
{'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 6, 10, 38, 28, 948000), 'item': 0.5, 'state': {'value1': 0.0, 'value2': 0.143, 'value3': 0.857}}
{'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 6, 10, 41, 11, 201000), 'item': 0.4, 'state': {'value1': 0.0, 'value2': 0.091, 'value3': 0.909}}
{'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 6, 11, 45, 25, 145000), 'item': 0.1, 'state': {'value1': 0.0, 'value2': 0.083, 'value3': 0.917}}
{'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 6, 11, 46, 31, 508000), 'item': 0.1, 'state': {'value1': 0.0, 'value2': 0.0, 'value3': 1.0}}
{'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 6, 11, 46, 33, 120000), 'item': 0.1, 'state': {'value1': 0.0, 'value2': 0.214, 'value3': 0.786}}
{'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 6, 12, 36, 25, 695000), 'item': 0.0, 'state': {'value1': 0.0, 'value2': 0.0, 'value3': 1.0}}
{'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 6, 12, 37, 35, 721000), 'item': 0.0, 'state': {'value1': 0.0, 'value2': 0.0, 'value3': 1.0}}]
```

The desired output of the above example is: `[1.0, 0.76, 0.0, 0.833, 0.909, 0.857, 0.727, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` that is keeping also the most recent value (when there are multiple item values) by taking into account time. I have tried to solve it using if-else statements, however, I would like a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can you give an example of something you've tried unsuccessfully?

Comment: I have tried to implement if-else logic that actually worked properly but I would if is possible, something more elegant.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON file. If you have multiple objects in a JSON file, they need to be wrapped in an array.

Comment: JSON also requires double quotes around strings, not single quotes, and doesn't allow function calls.

Comment: @Barmar it also doesn't have `my_json =` in front of it. I think that's the parsed json :P

Comment: Now it's missing commas between each dictionary.

Comment: @AdamSmith That wasn't there before the edit.'

Comment: This isn't about JSON, it's just a Python list of dictionaries.

Comment: "11 dimensions"? I think you mean 11 elements, not 11 dimensions.

Comment: This is indeed a Python list of dictionaries. Use a linter to be sure that the JSON you post is valid: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary whose keys are the `item` values. Loop through `my_json`, assigning `value3` to the corresponding element.

```
d = {}
for i in my_json:
    d[i['item']] = i['state']['value3']
```

I'm assuming the list is already sorted by the timestamp; if not, sort the list first.

Answer (score 1):

I've extended the above solution to include sorting by time in case it is needed

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_json, key=lambda k: k['time'])    

d = {}
for i in sorted_list:
    d[i['item']] = i['state']['value3']
```